# Convert ellipse parameter from General parametric form to General polar form

Tags: conic-sections

I am facing problem to convert ellipse standard parameters. Everything I say here is refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse

I know what are the **General parametric form parameter** . Lets call them **$a$,$b$,$\varphi$, $t_X$, $t_Y$**

Now I need to find the **general polar form parameter**. I follow the equation in wikipedia
But I may misunderstand what it says.

**Here is what I think**

$$r_0 = \sqrt{tx^2+ty^2}$$ 
$$\theta_0 = \tan^{-1} \frac{t_Y}{t_X}$$ 
and 
$$ \phi =  \varphi$$

I think I am worng, because the output plot was not right. Please help

The following is my MATLAB code, the upper section is the general parametric form, I also draw the ellispe. The lower section is my incorrect general polar form

%==================

close all

```
            data = [0.6397 0.9520 15.9195 1.1430 -0.3844];

            a = data(1);
            b = data(2);
            ang = data(3);
            tranX = -data(4);
            tranY = -data(5);

            x = zeros(1,3601);
            y = zeros(1,3601);

            counter = 1;

            for t = 0:.1:360
            x(counter) = tranX + a*cosd(t)*cosd(ang) - b*sind(t)*sind(ang);
            y(counter) = tranY + a*cosd(t)*sind(ang) + b*sind(t)*cosd(ang);
            counter=counter+1;
            end

            figure;plot(x,y)

            %=============================================

            r0 = norm([tranX tranY]);
            theta0 = atand(tranY/tranX);
            rho = ang;
            rr  = zeros(1,3601);
            counter = 1;

            for t = 0:.1:360
                P(counter) = r0*[(b*b-a*a)*cosd(t+theta0-2*rho)+(a*a+b*b)*cosd(t-theta0)];
                R(counter) = (b*b-a*a)*cosd(2*t-2*rho)+a*a+b*b;
                Q(counter) = sqrt(2)*a*b*sqrt(R(counter)-2*r0*r0*(sind(t-theta0))^2);
                rr(counter) = (P(counter)+Q(counter))/R(counter);
                counter = counter + 1;
            end

            [XX,YY] = pol2cart((0:.1:360)*2*pi/180,rr);

            figure; plot(XX,YY,'.')
```

Comment: Please, write in $\LaTeX$. You can learn some codes like, `${x}^{2n+1}$` makes ${x}^{2n+1}$, `$\sin \theta$` makes $\sin \theta$ and `$T_{2n}$` makes $T_{2n}$

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: General parametric form parameter does not require origin inside ellipse, but I think general polar form parameter does because 'Q' in general polar form parameter could be complex number if r0 is large

Answer (score 0):

Maybe $r=\sqrt{t_X^2+t_Y^2}$. Else you got a part of a circle.

(I'm french. I hope you will excuse my english.)

Comment: I did it like this, but Peter T.off edit my question and he had a typo